# Trying to dynamically add new rows in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Hi I'm fairly new to React and I am trying to add new items to an array which are then displayed when a button is pressed.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDi3r.png)

A new title will be added at the bottom with the name that's inputted in the textbox.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Container, Button, Input } from "reactstrap";

function Row(props) {
  return (
    <li class="columnBox">
      {props.title}
    </li>
  );
}

export default function App() {

  const rows = [
    { title: "title 1"},
    { title: "title 2"},
    { title: "title 3"}
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Add new titles</h1>

      <form onSubmit={() => {
        event.preventDefault();
        rows.push({ title: "newRow"})
      }}>
      <Input type="text" name="email" id="newRow" placeholder="" />
      <Button type="submit">add</Button>
        </form>

        <ul>
        {rows.map((row) => (
              <Row title={row.title} />
            ))}
        </ul>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what is the problem

Comment: The problem is that the new titles that are added to the array do not display

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to use `state`. React application will normaly rerender when there is a change in `state` or `prop`.

```
export default function App() {

    const [rows, setRows] = useState([
      { title: "title 1"},
      { title: "title 2"},
      { title: "title 3"}
    ]);
  
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Add new titles</h1>
  
        <form onSubmit={() => {
          event.preventDefault();
          setRows([
              ...rows,
              {title: "newRow"}
          ])
        }}>
        <Input type="text" name="email" id="newRow" placeholder="" />
        <Button type="submit">add</Button>
          </form>
  
          <ul>
          {rows.map((row) => (
                <Row title={row.title} />
              ))}
          </ul>
  
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use useState and update the state

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Container, Button, Input } from "reactstrap";
export default function App() {
    const [rows, setRows] = useState([
      { title: "title 1"},
      { title: "title 2"},
      { title: "title 3"}
    ]);
  
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Add new titles</h1>
  
        <form onSubmit={() => {
          event.preventDefault();
          setRows([
              ...rows,
              {title: "newRow"}
          ])
        }}>
        <Input type="text" name="email" id="newRow" placeholder="" />
        <Button type="submit">add</Button>
          </form>
  
          <ul>
          {rows.map((row) => (
                <Row title={row.title} />
              ))}
          </ul>
  
      </div>
    );
  }
```